# How to get eveything after a certain pattern in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consider this is the data in column v:

Challenge: I want to extract the first set of alphanumeric characters only after the keyword 'theTags',

```
create table sample as
select ' dsaljkdlsakj 232 11 sdlksaffeoi theTags: 123456 , wewds l [ ] ' as v
union 
select 'weqreqf fdffrok skdjsa theTags 1233228, dsdad 22 ' as v
union 
select ' eeofkdspof kosadk 3e theTags: ab123232 & [dsda ] '  as v
union
select ' eeofkdspof kosadk 3e theTags23248ab & [dsda ] '  as v
union
select ' eeofkdspof kosadk 3e theTags 23233ab# & [dsda ] '  as v
```

I tried the following, the output only shows 'theTags'

```
select reg_exp_substr(v,'theTags',1,1,'e') AS result from sample
```

I have also tried, this only works on certain patterns

```
select 
SPLIT_PART(reg_exp_substr(v,'theTags [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'), ' ',2) as result 
from sample
```

But that doesn't give the output I want, seems like a lot of hard coding needs to be done to get exact pattern.

**Desired Output:**

result

123456

1233228

ab123232

23248ab

23233ab (Note we don't want the # here)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/2xLJLV/1

Comment: Did you tag the right database? `reg_exp_substr` is not a Snowflake thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved for Snowflake (as the question tagged this db), using groups with `()`:

```sql
select *, regexp_substr(v,'theTags[^a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)',1,1,'e')
from sample_1;
```

[image]